# Why does navbar appear on top of the scrollbar?

Tags: css

The navbar seems to be on top of the scrollbar (note the horizontal line), but I want it to end right next to the scrollbar.

[image]

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 102;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.header-content {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
} 

.app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I've never seen this happen before, and puzzled by why this happens. 
How do I get the navbar to end right next to the scrollbar?

Comment: Is this the “normal” scrollbar applied to the whole document, or is this the scrollbar of an element inside the page that has `overflow` set …? Please show a proper [mcve].

Comment: @misorude the scrollbar belongs to `.app` , which covers the whole page

Comment: Well there’s your answer then … Your header is 100% wide (because of left and right 0), and `.app` also is 100% wide - but the latter has a scrollbar shown _inside_ of that 100% width. (This behaves differently only when the scrollbar is applied to the root element.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you!

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```